# PHP Use foreach dynamic table headers in query for Rows

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi have a mysql table "positions" :

`posID posName    posQty
12    Agent        20
13    Supervisor   3
14    Manager      1
16    Teamlead     4`

I am using  a join to a mysql table "departments", what I need is to dynamically load posName in the column headers of the echoed table, then show posQty count in each respective column  / row intersection:

`Dept     Agent Supervisor Manager Teamlead
sales       4       1        1       2
support     6       1        0       1
hr          10      1        0       1`

What I have:

```
mysql_select_db("callcenter");
$query = "SELECT * FROM cscc_stakeholders JOIN employee ON employee.stakeholder_code = cscc_stakeholders.stakeholder_code
LEFT JOIN cscc_segments ON cscc_segments.segment_code = employee.segment_code GROUP BY cscc_stakeholders.stakeholder_code";
$sql = @mysql_query($query);
echo "<div><font size=\"3\"><table class=\"table table-bordered table-hover\" id=\"ticket_search_table\"><caption>By Segment</caption>";
$queryhead = "SELECT posName FROM cscc_headcount GROUP BY posName ORDER BY hcountId ASC";
$queryemployee = "SELECT posName FROM cscc_headcount GROUP BY posName";
$sqlhead = @mysql_query($queryhead);
    echo "<thead style=\"background-color:#424242; color: #E6E6E6\"><br/>";
    echo("<tr><th></th>");
    while($rowhead = @mysql_fetch_array($sqlhead)){
    $positions = array();
    foreach ($rowhead as $row_value){}
     $positions[] = $row_value; 
print_r($positions);
    echo("<td>".$row_value."</td>");}
```

Comment: and your query is  .... ?

Comment: sorry, edited post